# calculating $P(A \cup B)$

Tags: probability

Given

$$P(A \cap B)=\frac{1}{4} $$
$$P(A^c)=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Find $P(A \cup B)$

Basically this is what I did:

$$P(A)=1-P(A^c) \rightarrow P(A)=\frac{2}{3}$$

$$P(A \cup B)= P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$

$$\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{11}{12}$$

Does this work? I was confusing myself thinking the total probabilities did not add up to one. If what I think is correct we can say $P((A \cap B)^c)=\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: It's all right..

Comment: Yes, except for the last equation. You know that $P((A\cup B)^c)=1/12$. But $(A\cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c \neq (A\cap B)^c$.